# Finding a lower bound for a definite integral

Tags: calculus

$$
\frac{16}{\pi^3} \leq \int_0^1 \cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}}(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{4}}\, \text{d}x \leq \sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{32}}
$$

I encountered a question asking to show the upper and lower bounds of a definite integral. I found this upper bound could be solved with Cauchy–Schwarz inequality but had very little idea about the lower bound here. I suppose that $\pi^3$ in the denominator might come from integrating by parts, but have tried and made no progress...
I would be very grateful if someone may offer some hints or answers. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the inequality $1-x \leq \cos(\pi x /2)$ ? Using this inequality along with $(1-x^2) \leq (1 - x^2)^{3/4}$ for $x \in [0,1]$, I found that the given integral should be $\geq 0.42\dots $. I thought maybe that direction will get you to prove the whole thing.

Comment: @user669545 It turns out that it can be solved by just using $(1-x^2) \leq (1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{4}}$ for $x \in [0, 1]$. Thank you very much! :)